# Postfix would not auto-create the Maildir for incoming mails

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail

I am trying to setup a mail server. I went over tons of tutorials on how to do this with `Postfix` + `dovecot` + `MySQL`, but none was error-proof and I always got stuck at some point with an error. So I  decide to configure the mail server step by step by my own. So far I have installed `Postfix` and `ViMbAdmin` as my postfix-admin interface. I managed to link the database with Postfix. Everything is fine but one! The Postfix would not auto-create the Maildir for incoming mails.

The following is a sample `mail.log` output for an incoming email:

```
postfix/smtpd[22086]: connect from mail-lf0-f45.google.com[209.85.215.45]
postfix/smtpd[22086]: C92B461E5B: client=mail-lf0-f45.google.com[209.85.215.45]
postfix/cleanup[22090]: C92B461E5B: message-id=<BLAH@mail.gmail.com>
postfix/qmgr[21732]: C92B461E5B: from=<BLAH-SENDER@gmail.com>, size=4535, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/virtual[22080]: C92B461E5B: to=<BLAH-RCVR@XXX.net>, orig_to=<BLAH-ALIAS@XXX.net>, relay=virtual, delay=0.13, delays=0.13/0/0/0, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/mail/vhosts/XXX.net/BLAH-RCVR/mail: unable to create lock file /var/mail/vhosts/XXX.net/BLAH-RCVR/mail.lock: No such file or directory)
postfix/smtpd[22086]: disconnect from mail-lf0-f45.google.com[209.85.215.45]
```

If I **manually** create the `/var/mail/vhosts/XXX.net/BLAH-RCVR/` directory, everything will go fine. I want the application auto-create the directory so I don't have to create it for every user I add to system!

What am I missing in here?

---

P.S: I've double checked the permission on `/var/mail/vhosts/` the postfix should be able to `RWX` the directory.

Comment: Normally you would instruct Postfix to give the incoming mails to Dovecot and let Dovecot handle the sorting. That's how i did it

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into the same issue migrating Postfix.  In the `/etc/postfix/vmailbox` file you need to format the target directory of the email address with a trailing slash "/" or it will puke that error:

**/etc/postfix/vmailbox** Specimen Entry:

```
terrence@test.com test.com/terrence/
```

Note the trailing forward-slash at the end of the target path for mail `test.com/terrence/`

If that's missing, you'll get that error puked that you referenced:

```
 unable to create lock file /var/mail/vhosts/XXX.net/BLAH-RCVR/mail.lock
```

After you add the trailing forward slashes on the end of every target path for all your email addresses in `/etc/postfix/vmailbox` then of course execute:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/vmailbox
```

A bit late, but when I bumped into this issue myself I found your post so when I solved the problem, felt it was worth answering your question; better late than never!